# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'syft.frameworks'

Tags: python, iot, federated-learning, pysyft

I am trying to work on this example of Federated Learning.
https://towardsdatascience.com/federated-learning-3097547f8ca3
I have installed the PySyft package but I am getting this error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call 
last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10416/238857884.py in <module>
     9 import numpy as np
     10 import syft as sy
---> 11 from syft.frameworks.torch.federated import utils
     12 from syft.workers.websocket_client import WebsocketClientWorker

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'syft.frameworks'
```

Comment: IOT always makes me wonder which device you installed the module and where you ran the code. Also, please provide a [mcve]. That said, this might be a bug or an incompatible change in a newer version. You'll have to provide much more info than that you can't import a module.

Comment: I just want to run this example. please kindly take a look if you can help me. https://towardsdatascience.com/federated-learning-3097547f8ca3

Answer (score 0):

use this library
import syft.frameworks.torch.fl.utils as utils

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).